# Как исключить директорию из проверки catchALL?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Вот правило vue-router, которое не работает:

```
{
    path: "/:catchAll(^(?!specialFolder).*)",
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound
},
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исключить директорию из проверки на 404 страницу?
Чтобы при отсутствии файла в данной директории не было перехода на 404, а выбрасывалась ошибка, которую можно отловить в catch?

```
axios.get('/specialFolder/' + filename + '.txt').catch(()=>console.log('file not found'));
```

Answer (score 1):

В vue-router версии 4.* похоже ожидается такой синтаксис шаблона:

```
{
  path: '/:catchAll(specialFolder(.*)*)',
  name: 'NotFound',
  component: NotFound
},
```

, либо

```
{
  path: '/specialFolder',
  /* .... */
  children: [
    {
      path: ':catchAll(.*)*',
      name: 'NotFound',
      component: NotFound
    },
  ],
},
```

Таким образом, в пропс `catchAll` маршрута должен попадать массив фрагментов пути, например `['foo', 'bar.txt']` при запросе `/specialFolder/foo/bar.txt`.

*// В первом случае, я не уверен относительно попадания фрагмента `'specialFolder'` в массив, и не будет ли он соединен с последующим фрагментом - это надо проверять практически. Даже сомнительно что первый вариант вообще будет работать как предполагается - опять же, нужны практические тесты, смотреть что приходит в пропс и т.д..*

---

Регулярки в шаблонах теперь не используются! То есть, шаблоны в PCRE-like синтаксисе, но это не буквально рег.выражения... библиотека использует свой собственный разбор шаблонов.
См. описание соотв. ломающего изменения в руководстве по миграции, глава [Catch all / 404 Not found Route](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removed-star-or-catch-all-routes):

> Vue Router doesn't use `path-to-regexp` anymore, instead it implements its own parsing system that allows route ranking and enables dynamic routing.

Comment: В общем, суть ответа в синтаксисе `(.*)*` параметра пути - а насчет правильности шаблонов (и где там вложенность реально нужна, и где нет) я крайне-крайне не уверен, т.к. настраиваю роутер очень редко и по докам, не запоминая. Если в примерах допущена ошибка, буду признателен за правку/коммент.